# Why does Collections.UnmodifiableMap.UnmodifiableEntrySet override the stream() method?

Tags: java, oop, collections, java-stream, overriding

While looking at the source code, I could see that the `stream()` method has been overridden in `Collections.UnmodifiableMap.UnmodifiableEntrySet`. But the code seems to be identical to `Collection.stream()` except the return type in `Collections.UnmodifiableMap.UnmodifiableEntrySet.stream()` is more specific to be `Stream<Entry<K,V>>` rather than just `Stream<E>` as in `Collection.stream()`.

The `spliterator()` method is different in both classes, but even if `stream` is not overriden I think that the `UnmodifiableEntrySet.spliterator()` would be invoked from `Collection.stream()` if the object is of type `UnmodifiableEntrySet`.

So, is there any reason why the `stream` method was overriden?

**Collection.java**

```java
@Override
default Spliterator<E> spliterator() {
    return Spliterators.spliterator(this, 0);
}
 
default Stream<E> stream() {
    return StreamSupport.stream(spliterator(), false);
}
```

**Collections.UnmodifiableMap.UnmodifiableEntrySet.java**

```java
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Spliterator<Entry<K,V>> spliterator() {
    return new UnmodifiableEntrySetSpliterator<>(
        (Spliterator<Map.Entry<K, V>>) c.spliterator());
}

@Override
public Stream<Entry<K,V>> stream() {
    return StreamSupport.stream(spliterator(), false);
}
```

Comment: Simply because `UnmodifiableEntrySet` is a set of `Entry` while `Collection` is generic. I am not sure what's confusing you.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat Yes. My question was why should `UnmodifiableEntrySet` override `stream()` method if the the method body is exactly identical to `Collection.stream()`

Comment: @AniketSahrawat I was able to somewhat find a solution after some debugging.

Comment: @GauthamM - `Stream<Entry<K,V>>` is not a `Stream<E>`. Another example is `List<String>` is not a `List<Object>`.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash https://stackoverflow.com/a/66198058/7804477 these are my findings. I had tried removing the overriden `stream` from `UnmodifiableEntrySet` and `UnmodifiableCollection`, such that the `stream` call would go to `Collection` and `spliterator` call would invoke the overriden version in `UnmodifiableEntrySet`. What I understand from your point is that the returned stream would be a generic one and it would not be a stream of `Entry`. If that was true, then I should not be able to invoke `map(Entry::value)` on that stream. But I was able to do it. Please review my answer as well

Comment: I misread your question yesterday. If you take a look at the implementations of `stream`, you will notice that it has been overridden in 7 places. The relevant overrides are in `UnmodifiableCollection` and then again in `UnmodifiableEntrySet`. `UnmodifiableCollection#stream` is basically delegating the call to whatever `Collection` was passed. If there is no override in `UnmodifiableEntrySet`, the call would be delegated to the original `Collection` (which is mutable).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below Java Doc / program comes from *openjdk 14 2020-03-17*.

### The main reason to override `spliterator` and `stream` is to ensure the entry of `UnmodifiableEntrySet` is unmodified.

From comment of `UnmodifiableEntrySet`:

> We need this class in addition to UnmodifiableSet as Map.Entries themselves permit modification of the backing Map via their setValue operation. This class is subtle: there are many possible attacks that must be thwarted.

To begin, `UnmodifiableEntrySet` extends `UnmodifiableSet` which extends `UnmodifiableCollection`.
In `UnmodifiableCollection`, proxy pattern is used to avoid modifying the backing `Collection` *c*, most method just call the backing `Collection` method, like `spliterator` and `stream`:

```java
    @Override
    public Spliterator<E> spliterator() {
        return (Spliterator<E>)c.spliterator();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public Stream<E> stream() {
        return (Stream<E>)c.stream();
    }
```

---

So if `UnmodifiableEntrySet` does not override those methods, the behavior will follows `UnmodifiableCollection` implementation, and the backing entries will be exposed and can be modified through [`Entry#setValue`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.Entry.html#setValue(V)).

Hence `spliterator` and `stream` methods are overridden and `UnmodifiableEntrySetSpliterator` is introduced to wrap all access to the backing entry with `UnmodifiableEntry`, ensuring the entry can not be modified.

### Why `UnmodifiableCollection` override `stream`?

It seems that there is no need to override `stream` in `UnmodifiableCollection`, as we can just use default implementation in `Collection` (just create stream by the `spliterator`).
But the author decided to override `stream` using backing `Collection c` `stream` method, one of the possible reason is the backing `Collection` may override `stream` method for performance reason, e.g. `Collections.CopiesList`, or it's  `spliterator` method does not fulfill the requirement according to [Collection#stream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#stream())

> This method should be overridden when the spliterator() method cannot return a spliterator that is IMMUTABLE, CONCURRENT, or late-binding. (See spliterator() for details.)

Comment: This explains most of it. But I have few doubts. https://stackoverflow.com/a/66198058/7804477 - This is what I tried. In my `CollectionsCopy` class I had removed the overriden `stream` from both `UnmodifiableEntrySet` & `UnmodifiableCollection`. Then I tried `unmodifiableMap.entrySet().stream().findFirst().orElse(null)`. This actually returned an immutable entry. if I hadn't removed the overriden `stream` from `UnmodifiableCollection`, then mutable entry was returned as expected. Was overriding `stream` really required in `UnmodifiableCollection`. Isn't overriding `spliterator` enough?

Comment: @Gautham M, I agree that is not really required. But the author decided to use backing `Collection c` `stream` method by default, I think one of the reason is `c` may override `stream` method for performance reason, e.g. `Collections.CopiesList`.

Comment: @GauthamM I believe samabcde's answer is correct, and in fact the override of UnmodifiableEntrySet.stream() is required. I'm not sure why your example didn't work. I modified my build of the JDK to remove that override, and the stream contained mutable entries, thus allowing the unmodifiable map to be modified.

Comment: @StuartMarks Yes, I was able to get mutable entries if I hadn't removed the overridden `stream` in `UnmodifiableCollection`. If I had removed that as well, then the entry would be immutable.

Comment: @GauthamM Oh yes, I understand your question now. It might have been possible to get away without the override of UnmodifiableCollection.stream, but it would have potentially made the code brittle under maintenance. The general rule for the wrapper collections is that they should override _everything_ so that they can be verified to protect their invariants without inspecting the entire class hierarchy.

Comment: @samabcde That is right. Could you please add the details in your second comment to the answer as well.

Comment: @StuartMarks Along with that, the overriding of `stream` for performance, in other classes  mentioned by samabcde  makes it necessary to override it in `UnmodifiableCollection`

Answer (score 0):

After copying the contents of `Collections.java` to a new class `CollectionsCopy.java`, I tried removing the `stream` method from `UnmodifiableEntrySet` then I did some debugging and was able to get to an answer.

`UnmodifiableEntrySet` extends `UnmodifiableSet` which extends `UnmodifiableCollection` which in turn implements `Collection`. Since `UnmodifiableCollection` has a field `final Collection<? extends E> c;`, it had to override the `stream()` as below

```
public Stream<E> stream() {
    return (Stream<E>)c.stream();
}
```

In the constructor of `UnmodifiableEntrySet` the `Set<? extends Map.Entry<? extends K, ? extends V>>` object is cast to raw `Set` type and passed to the `super` constructor.

```
super((Set)s);
```

The comment attached to the code was :

> Need to cast to raw in order to work around a limitation in the type
> system

So when I removed the `stream()` from `UnmodifiableEntrySet` (inside my `CollectionsCopy.java`), due to the raw type conversion, the `spliterator` method being invoked was that in the `Set` instead of the one in `UnmodifiableEntrySet`. This was because the field `c` in `UnmodifiableCollection` would be `Set` instead of `UnmodifiableEntrySet` and when `c.stream()` was invoked from `UnmodifiableCollection.stream()`, it would invoke `Set.spliterator()`. So, it was necessary for `UnmodifiableEntrySet` to override the implementation of `stream()` of `UnmodifiableCollection`.

Also, I tried removing the overriden `stream()` from `UnmodifiableCollection`. This time, it worked as expected as the `spliterator` was invoked from the `UnmodifiableEntrySet`.

**EDIT :**
Based on a few comments that suggested that the returned stream from `Collection` would not be a stream of `Entry` instead it would be just a `Stream`. But in such a case, I shouldn't be able to invoke any methods from the `Entry` class on the stream. But I was able to invoke `map(Entry::getValue)` on that stream. So , the stream returned was indeed a stream of type `Entry`.